# How to fix importerror when using cmd to run python code

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this Python file:

```
from riotwatcher import LolWatcher, ApiError
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import cgi, cgitb 
import sys

user = "TSP";
region = "EUW";

if region == 'NA':
    region = 'NA1';
elif region == 'BR':
    region = 'BR1';
elif region == 'LAN':
    region = 'LA1';
elif region == 'LAS':
    region = 'LA2';
elif region == 'OCE':
    region = 'OC1';
elif region == 'KR':
    region = 'KR';
elif region == 'JP':
    region = 'JP1';
elif region == 'EUNE':
    region = 'EUN1';
elif region == 'EUW':
    region = 'EUW1';
elif region == 'RU':
    region = 'RU';
elif region == 'TR':
    region = 'TR1';

# global variables
api_key = 'api key'
watcher = LolWatcher(api_key)
my_region = 'EUW1'

if region == 'NA1':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'BR1':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'LA1':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'LA2':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'OC1':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'KR':
    my_region1 = 'ASIA';
elif region == 'JP1':
    my_region1 = 'ASIA';
elif region == 'EUN1':
    my_region1 = 'EUROPE';
elif region == 'EUW1':
    my_region1 = 'EUROPE';
elif region == 'RU':
    my_region1 = 'EUROPE';
else:
    my_region1 = 'EUROPE';

me = watcher.summoner.by_name(my_region, 'TSP')
print(me)

# Return the rank status for User
my_ranked_stats = watcher.league.by_summoner(my_region, me['id'])
print(my_ranked_stats)

my_matches = watcher.match.matchlist_by_puuid(my_region1, me['puuid'])
#print(my_matches)

m1 = my_matches[0]
#print(m1)

# fetch last match detail
#last_match = my_matches['matches'][0]
match_detail = watcher.match.by_id(my_region1, m1)

participants = []
for row in match_detail['info']['participants']:
    participants_row = {}
    participants_row['summonerName'] = row['summonerName']
    participants_row['individualPosition'] = row['individualPosition']
    participants_row['championName'] = row['championName']
    participants_row['champLevel'] = row['champLevel']
    participants_row['kills'] = row['kills']
    participants_row['deaths'] = row['deaths']
    participants_row['assists'] = row['assists']
    participants_row['visionScore'] = row['visionScore']
    participants_row['goldEarned'] = row['goldEarned']
    participants_row['item0'] = row['item0']
    participants_row['item1'] = row['item1']
    participants_row['item2'] = row['item2']
    participants_row['item3'] = row['item3']
    participants_row['item4'] = row['item4']
    participants_row['item5'] = row['item5']
    participants_row['item6'] = row['item6']
    participants.append(participants_row)
df = pd.DataFrame(participants)
df
print(participants)
```

But I get this error when trying to run in cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Pythongym\Scripts\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from riotwatcher import LolWatcher, ApiError
  File "C:\Pythongym\Scripts\riotwatcher.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Deserializer import Deserializer
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I've been able to run this in Visual Studio Code with my Python global directory, and then to run it in cmd I copied that Python and made a folder to make it easier access, but now I can't run it with the same files in that directory as the one I do in my Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Are you sure that VSCode is using the same Python environment as the effective one from the command line?

Comment: I can not see the Deserialiser in the file that you have shown us, I believe we may have to know the project structure or see the contents of riotwatcher rather than the file we see right now.

Comment: When selecting the python interpreter for visual studio code its the same one i've copied in to the folder i talked about, so I would it as the same python environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to package it as an executable using pyinstaller(https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) then open cmd in the folder (right click open cmd window here on windows 7) or CD into the folder and run the executable. Sure if you use heavy packages and have to debug the code lot of time you should not do this I am just saying what I think would work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have already added the link

Answer (score 0):

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

To use relative imports you need an empty file named `__init__.py` in the same directory as `main.py`.